# Sort NSArray of NSDecimalNumber

Tags: swift, sorting, nsarray, nsdecimalnumber

`NSDecimalNumber` has a useful compare: method.

Rather then writing a wrapper around this compare method and then calling sortedArrayUsingFunction:context:, I would simply like to directly pass the `NSDecimalNumber` compare method to one of `NSArray's` sorted<...> methods.

What is the best way to do this using Swift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `NSArray` you can simply use `sortedArrayUsingSelector()`
and pass the `compare:` method as selector:

```
let array = NSArray(objects:
        NSDecimalNumber(integer: 30),
        NSDecimalNumber(integer: 20),
        NSDecimalNumber(integer: 10))
let sorted = array.sortedArrayUsingSelector("compare:")
// Swift 2.2 or later:
let sorted = array.sortedArrayUsingSelector(#selector(NSNumber.compare(_:)))

print(sorted) // [10, 20, 30]
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try something like this:

```
let num = NSDecimalNumber(integer: 1)
let num2 = NSDecimalNumber(integer: 2)

let arr: NSArray = [num, num2]

arr.sort { (num1, num2) -> Bool in
    return num1.compare(num) == .OrderedDescending
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I came up with two ways. The first honors using the `NSArray`. However, if you use `Array` it's a bit easier.

```
let decimalOne = NSDecimalNumber(double: 100.4)
let decimalTwo = NSDecimalNumber(double: 34.1)
let decimalThree = NSDecimalNumber(bool: true)
let array = NSArray(arrayLiteral: decimalOne, decimalTwo, decimalThree)

let sortedArray = array.sort { first, second in
    if let first = first as? NSDecimalNumber, second = second as? NSDecimalNumber {
        // Sorts small to large
        // Use NSComparisonResult.OrderedDescending for large to small sorting
        return first.compare(second) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending
    }

    // Return false since NSArray isn't bound to a specific type
    return false
}

// Using Array
let swiftArray = [decimalOne, decimalTwo, decimalThree]
let sortedSwiftArray = swiftArray.sort { $0.compare($1) ==  NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending }
```

Since you use the Array in the second option Swift can infer that it's an array of `NSDecimalNumber` and you don't have to do the checking of type that you had to do in the sorting of the NSArray.

Hope that helps.